# How to turn forEach to map - javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

```
const myData = {
  name: 'data1',
  phone: 12345678
  ...
}
const testArray = [{
  name: 'name',
  value: ''
}, {
  name: 'phone',
  value: ''
}, {
  ...
}]

testArray.forEach((field, index) => {
        if (field.name === 'name') {
          field.value = myData.name
        } else if (field.name === 'phone') {
          field.value = myData.phone || 87654321
        }
        // just example, I need to handle different field with different situation 
      })
```

It's very common situation when we fetch some data and give it value by the schema we defined.

If I don't want to see some judgment like if else, is there any idea to turn this code to function programing code ?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, nor do you show any attempt to do whatever that is yourself. Why `map`? What result do you want? What trouble are you running into creating that result?

Comment: Your question is still not clear at all, but I think I know what you mean. You want to process the object based on the value of a specific field?

Comment: forget map, I know in the outside, I can change forEach to map, but inside the if else statement how can I do?

Comment: Yea I think I know what you mean now. You should open a new question but ask it more clearly because this question is a bit of a mess.

Comment: Changed my answer. See if it helps now?

Answer (score 2):

You could return a new object for each iteration and map the result.

For the property `value`, I suggest to use an object, which could be easily extended for more key/value pairs.

```js
var testArray = [{ name: 'A', value: 'aa' }, { name: 'B', value: 'bb' }],
    result = testArray.map(field =>
        Object.assign(
            {},
            field,
            { value: { A: 'xxx', B: 'yyyyy' }[field.name] || field.value }
        ));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why `Object.assign`, instead of just returning `{field, value}`?

Comment: @torazaburo, i thought, if the need for returning a new array, then the old values should not be mutated.

Comment: I can't do like this, I need to handle different field with different situation ..

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: I'm changing the answer completely based on comments of OP

So you have a list of objects, each potentially different, and you want to process each item based on the value of a specific field.

For simplification I will assume the only thing common among your objects is a 'type' field, and you have an arbitrary number of possible values.

First, identify your values, and write a function to process each type.

The basic if-else approach would be something like:

```
if (object.type == 'user') {
    process_user(object);
} else if (object.type == 'notification') {
    process_notification(object);
} else if (object.type == 'comment') {
    process_comment(object)
}
```

So you want to replace the if-else chain with a magical functional construct?

You create a mapping from type to processing function:

```
var processors = {
    'user': process_user
    'notification': process_notification
    'comment': process_comment
}
```

Then you just lookup the proper function to process the object based on its type in this map, then you call it:

```
var fn = processors[object.type]
if(fn) {
    fn(object)
}
```

Comment: If he doesn't know to do that (if, in fact, it's even what he wants to do), what are the odds that he'll know *how* to do that?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume he wants to perform the same operation without mutating the original array

Comment: Actually..I want to change the data, but I wonder to know if there any best way to turn the "if else" to functional programming way ..@@

Comment: lol what? my bad for being too charitable.

Comment: sorry, my bad..I have a terrible expression to my question.

Comment: No, a round-trip through JSON isn't *remotely* a "proper deep clone."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's the most reliable way for copying plain data objects, but not objects with method or cyclic graphs

Comment: @hasen: Nope. JSON doesn't understand `undefined`, dates, regular expressions, other objects with prototypes other than `Object.prototype`, ... It's just completely the wrong tool for cloning, full stop.